# Running Brightway on the cloud

Tags: brightway

So, I'm running Brightway in a docker container on Microsoft Azure App Service. Since Brightway stores all data in a SQLite database, I was running into issues with losing all of my data due to the ephemeral nature of these containers in App service.

To solve this, I tried to mount an Azure File Share into the docker container. This worked but I still run into issues where the LCA database gets corrupted every now and then. It appears that even Azure doesn't recommend using a mounted Azure File Share for hosting a SQLite database (as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-linux#best-practices)).

Is there a way to run Brightway with a cloud-based SQL (or non-SQL) database at all?
If not, are there plans to support this going forward?

I need to run Brightway on the cloud as part of a web app. Would appreciate any suggestions/recommendations on how to achieve a reliable and persistent database that works with Brightway.